# Spotify javascript API - getting the genre of a song in a playlist

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm currently using the very cool app Exportify (https://github.com/watsonbox/exportify) to export Spotify playlists to CSV.

My javascript knowledge is terrible but I'm currently trying to include the genre of each track, and I'm having trouble retrieving it.

I'm assuming that:

- I have to get the genre through the artist.
- The playlist API returns a simple artist object that can only get me the ID, not the genre (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/)
- That to get the genre I'd have to do a further lookup of the artist using the artist ID (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#artist-object-full)

I can get the artist ID by adding

```
item.track.artists.map(function (artist) {
  return artist.id
}).join(', '),
```

to the code below in the `exportify.js` file.

```
var tracks = responses.map(function (response) {
  return response.items.map(function (item) {
    return [
      item.track.uri,
      item.track.id,
      item.track.name,
      item.track.artists.map(function (artist) {
        return artist.name
      }).join(', '),
      item.track.artists.map(function (artist) {
        return artist.id
      }).join(', '),
      item.track.album.name,
      item.track.disc_number,
      item.track.track_number,
      item.track.duration_ms,
      item.added_by == null ? '' : item.added_by.uri,
      item.added_at
    ].map(function (track) {
      return '"' + track + '"';
    })
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I can then get the artist genre based on the artist ID and add it as another column?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 4):

Use the "Get an Artist" endpoint in Spotify:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artist/

Calling this endpoint will get you the genres of an artist given his artist ID.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented it!

Below is the function from https://github.com/pavelkomarov/exportify/blob/master/exportify.js that makes all the requisite API queries. My `apiCall` function is also in that file. It's using `fetch`.

1. First I send off requests for chunks of songs from the playlist.
2. Then I agglomerate those messages in to a data table and set of artists.
3. Then I use the set of artists to query for genre information.
4. Then I join that to the data and write out to csv.

Because it's all happening over the network, each new step has to be wrapped in a `.then()` which is dependent upon previous objects getting resolved. Thankfully, in recent years JavaScript has gotten more elegant at this. https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

The live app lives [here](https://exportify.net). I've also created [a notebook](https://github.com/pavelkomarov/exportify/blob/master/taste_analysis.ipynb) to analyze the output.

```
csvData(access_token, playlist) {
    // Make asynchronous API calls for 100 songs at a time, and put the results (all Promises) in a list.
    let requests = [];
    for (let offset = 0; offset < playlist.tracks.total; offset = offset + 100) {
        requests.push(utils.apiCall(playlist.tracks.href.split('?')[0] + '?offset=' + offset + '&limit=100',
                access_token));
    }

    // "returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved"
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
    let artist_hrefs = new Set();
    let data_promise = Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
        return responses.map(response => { // apply to all responses
            return response.items.map(song => { // appy to all songs in each response
                song.track.artists.forEach(a => { artist_hrefs.add(a.href) });
                return [song.track.uri, '"'+song.track.name.replace(/"/g,'')+'"', '"'+song.track.album.name.replace(/"/g,'')+'"',
                    song.track.duration_ms, song.track.popularity, song.track.album.release_date,
                    '"'+song.track.artists.map(artist => { return artist.name }).join(',')+'"',
                    song.added_by.uri, song.added_at]
            });
        });
    });

    // Make queries on all the artists, because this json is where genre information lives. Unfortunately this
    // means a second wave of traffic.
    let genre_promise = data_promise.then(() => {
        let artists_promises = Array.from(artist_hrefs).map(href => utils.apiCall(href, access_token));
        return Promise.all(artists_promises).then(responses => {
          let artist_genres = {};
          responses.forEach(artist => { artist_genres[artist.name] = artist.genres.join(','); });
          return artist_genres;
        });
    });

    // join genres to the table, label the columns, and put all data in a single csv string
    return Promise.all([data_promise, genre_promise]).then(values => {
        [data, artist_genres] = values;

        data = data.flat();
        data.forEach(row => {
            artists = row[6].substring(1, row[6].length-1).split(','); // strip the quotes
            deduplicated_genres = new Set(artists.map(a => artist_genres[a]).join(",").split(",")); // join and split and take set
            row.push('"'+Array.from(deduplicated_genres).filter(x => x != "").join(",")+'"'); // remove empty strings
        });
        data.unshift(["Spotify URI", "Track Name", "Album Name", "Duration (ms)",
            "Popularity", "Release Date", "Artist Name(s)", "Added By", "Added At", "Genres"]);

        csv = '';
        data.forEach(row => { csv += row.join(",") + "\n" });
        return csv;
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As Potray said, you can connect to the endpoint getArtist. More specifically, the JSON returned will have a genre key. The genre key directly points to an array of genres.

response.genres will access this array.

You can test this out at [RapidAPI here.](https://rapidapi.com/package/SpotifyPublicAPI/functions/getArtist?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=SpotifyPublicAPI_GetArtist) I've specifically linked you to the getArtist endpoint. Here you can fill in the artist_id, click test, and see a sample response. RapidAPI will also generate a code snippet so you can just copy and paste the API call directly into your own code.

Here I'm testing out the getArtist endpoint with the Red Hot Chili Peppers artist_id "0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5":

[image]

You'll notice that the genre array contains 5 items: [ 'alternative rock', 'funk metal', 'funk rock', 'permanent wave', 'rock' ]

If you click CODE directly about the response on the right and sign in, you'll be able to access the code snippet, and paste it directly into your code. An example would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

note the genres referenced here do not match what you actually encounter in most of the api (eg. does not match `track.artist.genres`)

https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-available-genre-seeds/

this issue is outstanding:
https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/410